# Can intel xdk html5 based app work only when internet connection is enabled

Tags: javascript, android

I want my app not to be accessible without internet connection. I am developing app using Intel XDK by using HTML5 language . Now when I build my app that works without internet connection but I want my app to work only when internet connection is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the application.appcache to allow content to be stored and used from the cache, you can specify that all files (or perhaps just critical files that allow the app to start?) are listed under NETWORK.
"To ensure that the application requests the file from the server even if the cached resource is cached in the application cache, you can place that file in the NETWORK: section." 
http://apress.jensimmons.com/v5/pro-html5-programming/ch12.html
or check for connectivity using navigator.onLine or other methods - see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/workingoffthegrid/

Comment: Actually when i build the app it works in an offline mode whether net in connected or not. I want it should run on internet connection only .what code should i write

Answer (score 0):

List a file under NETWORK: that is used by the app each time and it will have to go to the internet to retrieve